# Edit android manifest correctly

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to use the flutter_foreground_plugin for my project but I'm having difficulty understanding how to edit the android manifest file.

**these are the required edits:**
[image]

**These are my interpretations of said edits:**
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I get the error

```
error: FlutterForegroundPlugin() has private access in FlutterForegroundPlugin
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new changjoopark.com.flutter_foreground_plugin.FlutterForegroundPlugin());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **[AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/ChangJoo-Park/flutter_foreground_service_plugin/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)** can help you how to configure your project.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="changjoopark.com.flutter_foreground_plugin_example"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Flutter ForegroundService Example"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="changjoopark.com.flutter_foreground_plugin.FlutterForegroundService"/>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="23"
        tools:overrideLibrary="changjoopark.com.flutter_foreground_plugin" />
</manifest>
```

You can also try to [download this example](https://github.com/ChangJoo-Park/flutter_foreground_service_plugin/tree/master/example) and try to run it on your machine so you can clear your doubts.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I made the necessary changes and also reduced the version of the package from 0.8.0 to 0.6.0

Comment: @Emmanuel How did you manage installing version 0.6.0 if you are using null safety?

Comment: I didn't. I used another package that works pretty well https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task

Answer (score 3):

Open FlutterForegroundPlugin.java
change from `private FlutterForegroundPlugin() {}` to `public FlutterForegroundPlugin() {}`